# Vaadin component tree possible?

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

Is there a way to create a component tree in Vaadin? I googled it but only learned that it was not possible 3 years ago.

For example In a nested tree, a leaf in tree should have a hidden panel that has groups of attributes like combos checkboxes and text fields, which will be visible when user clicks that leaf in the tree, there will also be a show/hide option.

How would you approach to this situation? Treetable can be a solution?

Or can I create/barrow a gwt widget for this and use it in vaadin? Is this a good approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combination of TreeTable and GeneratedColumn will be a good solution.

The GeneratedColumn will be use to show your comboBox/Textfield/checkBox.

If you're not familiar with GenratedColumn : [5.14.5 Generated Table Column](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html)

Regards, Éric

Comment: Thanks, can I also lay the ui components under the leaf but not on right side? Each leaf can have different number of ui components also.

Comment: @Spring is "not on right side" means to you "on another column" ?